# One hot encoded output to categorical value from a ML model

Tags: machine-learning, one-hot-encoding, kaggle

In my one .py file I created a model and saved the .pkl file of it to use afterward for analysis.
The model is formed using the code from this kaggle emotional data set
https://www.kaggle.com/shivamburnwal/speech-emotion-recognition
The issue is that when I am using this code's model to detect the emotion of new audio then the output is in one hot encoded format.
Is there any way using which I can get the actual emotion('happy','fear' etc.) instead of 1's and 0's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

prediction output is a list like this:

```
prediction = [0,0,0,0,1,0,0] , [0,1,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,1,0,0,0]
```

Then you can change them by using this code:

```
pred = []

for x in prediction:
    if x == [0,0,0,0,1,0,0]:
        pred.append('Sad')
    
    elif x == [0,1,0,0,0,0,0]:
        pred.append('Happy')
        
    elif x == [0,0,0,1,0,0,0]:
        pred.append('disgust')

print(pred)
```

output =

```
['Sad', 'Happy', 'disgust']
```

Please add more `elif` statement according to your need.

Comment: It is like this [0,0,0,0,1,0,0] , [0,1,0,0,0,0,0],  [0,0,0,1,0,0,0]   depending on the detected emotion from the audio , in total there are 7 emotions. every audio file is of 3s and it detects emotion identified in that duration.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please let me know if it worked or not.

Comment: I want an output in a list containing detected emotions , for eg. if the results are as follows - [0,0,0,0,1,0,0] , [0,1,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,1,0,0,0] then emotions are sad (as 1 is at 5th position) , happy (as 1 is at 2nd position) and disgust (as 1 is at 4th place).... if possible the output should be -> ['sad' , 'happy', 'disgust']   ..... would you please help me with this

Comment: I have edited my answer.  There are 7 emotions, so please add more `elif` statements for those, like I have added in that code. And let me know if it worked or not.

Comment: Yes, it did work,thanks, I can't believe that the solution was so easy